# Creation of a loop that takes in IP and subnet mask input from user, and converts these into Broadcast IP in C

Tags: c

I am trying to create a loop that takes in IP and subnet mask input from user, and converts those IPs to Broadcast IPs using the given inputs in C.

I am very new to programming. I have written some code which I am trying to use to do the required assignment. However, the assignment does not let you use arrays. I think I'm on the right track as I've written the necessary code to take input from the user; however, my mistakes are in the creation of the loop and setting up its criteria.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int inputIPAndSubnetMask(unsigned char* firstOctate, unsigned char* secondOctate, unsigned char* thirdOctate, unsigned char* fourthOctate, int subnetInput) {
    int i = 0;
    printf("Please input an IPv4 address: \n");
    int result = scanf("%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", firstOctate, secondOctate, thirdOctate, fourthOctate);
    while (i >= 0) {
        printf("Please enter a submask that's either 8, 16, 24, or 32: \n");
        int subMask = scanf("%d", &subnetInput);
        if (subMask == 8) {
            printf("%hhu\t%hhu\t%hhu\t%d\t\n", firstOctate, secondOctate, thirdOctate, 255);
            break;
        }
        else if (subMask == 16) {
            printf("%hhu\t%hhu\t%d\t%d\t\n", firstOctate, secondOctate, 255, 255);
            break;
        }
        else if (subMask == 24) {
            printf("%hhu\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\n", firstOctate, 255, 255, 255);
            break;
        }
        else if (subMask == 32) {
            printf("%d\t%d\t%d\t%d\t\n", 255, 255, 255, 255);
            break;
        }
        else {
            printf("Your subnet is wrong. Please try again.\n");
        }
    }
return result;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned char a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, e = 0, f = 0, g = 0, h = 0;

    inputIPAndSubnetMask(&a, &b, &c, &d, e);

    return 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong with the code that should be fixed? And how do I make my code more robust?

Comment: @user3121023 Thanks for the tip! The compiler now says warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘unsigned char *’ on line 16, 20, and 24. Why is that?

Answer (score -1):

You can make use of library functions from `<arpa/inet.h>`, I hope the following demonstration will help you to do so.

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct ipaddr_s
{
    uint8_t oct0;
    uint8_t oct1;
    uint8_t oct2;
    uint8_t oct3;
}ipaddr_t;

int main()
{
    uint32_t ip, bc, ch;
    ipaddr_t *addr;
    int i = 0x80000000;
    addr = (ipaddr_t*)&ip;
    printf("Enetr IP :");
    scanf("%hhu.%hhu.%hhu.%hhu", &addr->oct0, &addr->oct1, &addr->oct2, &addr->oct3);
    printf("Enter mask :");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    if (ch < 1 || ch > 32) {
        printf("wrong mask\n");
        return -1;
    }
    i = i >> (ch - 1);
    bc = ip | i;
    printf("broadcast address: %s\n", inet_ntoa(*(struct in_addr *) &bc));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: They said they aren't allowed to use arrays. It doesn't conform to the code they are asking.